# How can I mass cut PDFs to the correct smaller dimensions?

Tags: pdf, scanning

If I have pages from a book, so they're less than US letter size or A4, or whatever page size the scanner takes.   But let's say they got scanned in as that page size the scanner takes.  (Could be US letter size, could be could be A4 - the UK equivalent not exactly the same size but similar size)

How can I specify that I want to not necessarily rescale it to another size..(though that'd be good as a next after) but cut the excess white space off. For example

Ideally I want to do it for any arbitrary size.  So I want to be able to specify sizes. As the page sizes may be A4 for the bigger one like what a UK printer takes, and A5 for the smaller book one. Or not A5. But the key is that I have PDFs of a bigger page size, and I want output that is the correct page size to match the page I placed onto the scanner for scanning.

And preferably i'd want to do this for free.

As an example, I want to turn this-

[image]

Into this

[image]

Comment: well, not an answer, but no doubt a lot of scanning software has an option like 'automatically crop'. hp 'solution centre' has that, though granted that doesn't answer your question as you want it after it is scanned in not so well.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a Pdf printer. When you open the PDF in Adobe Reader and choose print you select this new Pdf printer and select the desired page size (in `Properties`). Make sure to select `Actual Size` under `Size options` and your Pdf will be printed **to a new Pdf** with the page "cut of" at the selected page size. (You can see this in the preview window on the right)

You can use any of the free available PDF-printer on the net. Like [PdfCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator), [Bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) or [CutePdf](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) to just name a few.

**Please note**: *A lot* of freeware tries to install toolbars and addons to support its own development. **If you don't want** such toolbars or addons **always** watch the options during installation of **all freeware software** and deselect the installation of those toolbars/addons.

[image: Print in Adobe Reader]

Comment: worth noting, pdfcreator pdfforge tries to install a toolbar, if not told not to. http://www.techsupportalert.com/freeware-forum/freeware-installation-and-usage/9066-bullzip-pdf-printer.html

Comment: True. Most freeware come with such toolbars/addons. I added the note to my answer. (It's almost automatism for me to deselect these addons) BTW There is another option to do what you asked and that is to feed the PDF through ghostscript with a different pagesize. (You can automate that for lots of PDFs) But the page needs to be shifted up because for a PDF point 0,0 is lower left. and you need to calculate manually by how much. If you need it i could make a separate answer for that but i think it's only needed if you have dozens or hundreds of pdfs.

Comment: looks like  a good answer, will be   a while till i give it a try. but i  will

Answer (score 1):

Briss does just what you want with a graphical user interface.  It is written in Java, so it runs on multiple platforms.  From the home page:  "This project aims to offer a simple cross-platform (Linux, Windows, Mac OSX) application for cropping PDF files. A simple user interface lets you define exactly the crop-region by fitting a rectangle on the visually overlaid pages.  It's licensed under GPL!"

http://briss.sourceforge.net/

There is a forum thread for Briss in the mobileread.com PDF forum:

http://www.mobileread.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=184

Comment: Please do not post "link"-only answers. That site could change or become unavailable in the future. Please explain the program referred to with download-site and how to use it.

Comment: Briss is a fantastic piece of software but I agree with @Rik. You should expand on your answer.

Comment: I expanded my answer.